# Why preg_replace giving this result

Tags: php

I am using this preg_replace

```
  echo preg_replace('/.*/','r','string');
```

https://eval.in/720293

I was expecting it should output `r`

But the output is

> rr

Can someone explain why it echo two r ?

Comment: Because `.*` *also* matches the empty string. (Somewhere, once.)

Comment: preg finds "abcd", which fits `.*`. then continues to look, finds the empty string, which, too, fits `.*`, since the star operator means "zero or more". so it has two matches. don't want the empty string? use `.+` - the plus operator meaning "once or more".

Comment: thankksssss i got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because preg_replace uses global flag and `.*` matches first the whole string and then the empty string at the end and therefore you see two times the r. 
If you want to replace just the string you have to be more explicit with the pattern. For an example, you can use the following `^.*`.
Other option is to add limit to preg_replace to replace only the first match:
preg_replace('/.*/','r','string', 1)